# copy a file using c language system calls

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm exploring system calls in c programming language and trying out some examples on copying a file. I am running into issues where I have an original text file containing a single line "The quick brown fox..." to be copied and then the result contains data that is not intended to be there.  Any ideas or tips I should know on how to fix this?

When I tried to run the code example ./copy sample.txt new_sample.txt (*similar to **cp** command*) I get this ouput on the terminal:

```
$./copy sample.txt new_sample.txt
argv[0] = ./copy
argv[1] = sample.txt
argv[2] = new_sample.txt
ERROR: couldn't write whole buffer
Segmentation fault: 11
$
```

given that there's an error on the terminal there is a file created named new_sample.txt opening it using vim editor reveals this result.

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
>   ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@à¯¾dÿ^?^@^@^@^@¾dÿ^?^@^@<9b>¿¾dÿ^?^@^@Àú½dÿ^?^@^@^_ã¾dÿ^?^@^@@ü½dÿ^?^@^@<90>û½dÿ^?^@^@@û½dÿ^?^@^@^Z^S¾dÿ^?^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@þ^D^A^@^@^@À^E¾dÿ^?^@^@^@^@^@^@ÿ^?^@^@
>   ^G¾dÿ^?^@^@0^G¾dÿ^?^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@pû½dÿ^?^@^@×^Eä¦÷[<87>´^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

here's an example code i have: (filename: copy.c)

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr.h" /* contains stdlib, sys/types, stdio.h, unistd, error, string.h */

#ifndef BUF_SIZE /* Allow "cc -D" to override definition */
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inputFd;
    int outputFd;
    int openFlags;
    mode_t filePerms;
    ssize_t numRead;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    /* check for the inputs */
    int arg_count=0;
    for (arg_count; arg_count < argc; arg_count++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", arg_count, argv[arg_count]);

    if (argc != 3 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
        usageErr("%s old-file new-file\n", argv[0]);

    /* open input and outpu files */
    inputFd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (inputFd == -1)
        errExit("opening file %s", argv);

    openFlags = O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC;
    filePerms = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH; /*rw-rw-rw*/

    outputFd = open(argv[2], openFlags, filePerms);

    if (outputFd == -1)
        errExit("opening file %s", argv[2]);

    /* transfer data until we encounter end of input or an error */

    while ((numRead = read(inputFd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        if (write(outputFd, buf, BUF_SIZE) != numRead)
            fatal("couldn't write whole buffer");
    }

    if (numRead == -1)
        errExit("read");

    if (close(inputFd) == -1)
        errExit("close input");
    if (close(outputFd) == -1)
        errExit("close output");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: If on Linux you also might like to have look at the `sendfile()` system call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop reads too much at the end of the file since the file may not be a multiple of `BUF_SIZE` in length. So if you have 20 bytes in your file, you'll get the original 20 bytes copied, plus 1004 bytes of junk (whatever's in your buffer).

Do this to write the number of bytes you read to the output:

```
while ((numRead = read(inputFd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    if (write(outputFd, buf, numRead) != numRead)
        fatal("couldn't write whole buffer");
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that's really great!!  I really appreciate your kind answer! I didn't realized that!! Thanks a lot - here have my :like: